# Getting travel insurance for multiple travels in a month

Tags: air-travel, india, insurance

I have travel plans via air in a particular month where I will be going to and fro between two places. If I book tickets via online travel agency (Yatra/MakeMyTrip), they offer me to get travel insurance. But I have to buy insurance multiple times (for each return trip in my case) increasing my cost.

Can I buy insurance which covers all my air travels for, say, an entire month (within which I have my multiple air travels)? Are there any dos and don'ts that I need to be aware of?

Comment: I have no idea about India but in the UK annual insurance is available and may, or may not, be cheaper than lots of single trip policies.

Comment: A quick search on Google reveals at least one company in India that offers an annual travel insurance policy. Search for 'multi trip travel insurance', contact the companies you find and explain what you need. You shouldn't have trouble getting a suitable policy, but whether it's cheaper is a different question.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to buy travel insurance for the entire duration of your travel which includes multiple trip. However, you will most likely need to buy it as a separate product rather than a bundled one. Try reaching out to [Tata AIG](https://www.tataaig.com/travel-insurance) or [ICICI Lombard](https://www.icicilombard.com/travel-insurance), they should be able to issue an insurance suiting your needs.